# Why does my image hover move to the left?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with some overlay text. Whenever I hover my mouse over my image, the content displayed once hovered is moved to the left of the original image. The hovered content is shifted 69 pixels to the left. I want the hovered content to be directly hovered over the image. How can I fix this?

[image: Hover Error]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="container col-lg-3">
        <img src="Images/Coding.jpg" alt="" class="image">
     <div class="description">
        <h6 class="titles">
            Coding
        </h6>
        <br>
        <i class="far fa-keyboard fa-2x"></i>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>
            Projects | Learning | Design
        </p>
    </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">
                <h5>
                    Take a peak at my offers, current projects, and qualifications
                </h5>
                <br>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" href="coder.html" role="button">
                    Explore more
                </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.image {
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
background-color: #008CBA;
}


.text {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Your css doesn't have any `:hover` effect

Comment: Thanks for flagging! Updated my post with the :hover effect.

Comment: can you please add jsfiddle of your work so we can help you better.

Comment: look at this https://jsfiddle.net/9rmuvyLn/ . I can't find where is your problem here? code works perfectly!

Comment: perhaps a browser caching issue. try ctrl+f5

Answer (score 0):

Because container class tacking a padding so please add `padding:0px`;

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding:0px;
}
```